# How to prove the following statement?

Tags: formal-proofs

a=b ∨ a=c ∨ b=c = T

I have expanded the LHS as follows. But have no clue how to continue from there

(a=>b)∧(b=>a) ∨ (a=>c)∧(c=>a) ∨ (b=>c)∧(c=>b)

Link for the question [Q (p)]. 
http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~hehner/aPToP/solutions/Ex6.pdf

The solution is not understood.

Comment: Could you give more background about the questions? I am not understanding what we are proving and why we are doing so!

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh will you follow the link provided. It has similar proof questions like this.

Comment: Please, instead of posting links, could you type some words in order to explain what you are talking about? If $a$, $b$ and $c$ represent propositions, what is the meaning of $a = b$? What is T?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, a=b means if and only if, a=>b means if then, and T means binary Truth or 1 .

Comment: @DhananjayaSenanayake It does have the proof. But, I am not getting the context. Why is it so? What are $a, b, c$? Kindly clarify!

Comment: @DhananjayaSenanayake $a = b$ does not "mean" if and only if $a \geq b$. You can say "if $a = b$, then $a \geq b$" but not the converse. Because, $5 \geq 4$ but $5 \neq 4$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh, I am using these laws to solve these questions. http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~hehner/aPToP/laws.pdf. Please note that I have a only a basic understanding on these laws.

Comment: The links you are sharing are very vague and I do not understand the meaning of $=$. Two logical statements cannot be "equal". They can at most be "equivalent", which is denoted by $\equiv$. However, kindly explain what you want in your question otherwise we won't be able to help you out.

Comment: Suggestion: **Don't** use that book.  That is not an standard use of the symbols, nor common nomenclature for the rules.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh a=b = (a=>b)∧(b=>a). This is how it is defined in the book. Unfortunately I have no any other context to provide. If you could solve this , it is highly appreciated.

Comment: @GrahamKemp is right!

Comment: @DhananjayaSenanayake The problem is, $a = b \vee b = c \vee a = c = T$ is not making any sense. Even if I consider the usual symbols and make it $a = b \vee b = c \vee a = c \equiv T$, even then, what do we have to prove here is not clear. Also, to prove something, we need some hypothesis, which is lacking!

Comment: You appear to wish to prove $\def\too{\leftrightarrow}(a\too b)\lor(a\too c)\lor(b\too c)$ in more commonly accepted symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say without loss of generality that $a<=>b$. Then, a and b are both true or both false, which means that $a=>b$ and $b=>a$.